# reading in files using a function in R

Tags: r, function, csv, dataframe

I am trying to create a function that would read in files and change one of the column names. Could someone please let me know why this code does not output a dataframe but it outputs the column name that has been changed instead?

```
f <- function(path, name) {
ind <- gregexpr(pattern ='_GeneSum2.txt',name)
new_name <- substr(name,1,ind[[1]][1]-1)
data_loc <- file.path(path,name)
read <- read.delim(data_loc)
names(read)[2] <- paste(names(read)[2], 'addition', sep = '_')
}
```

The output dataframe I am expecting is something like

```
name_1  name_2_addition
john    3
tom     5
sam     6
```

If I remove the last line of the code, I get the dataframe with the original column names.

Thanks very much.

Comment: You should add a line to your function to actually return the updated data frame: `return(read)`. Otherwise you are returning the last expression which was the `names()<-` assignment and assignments generally return the newly assigned value(s).

Comment: Thanks very much. It did the trick!